# R package 'parallel' in R 4.0.3

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Currently I have problems installing and loading the R package 'parallel'. As far as I know the R package has been included to R Core and after I've updated to R version 4.0.3 the package is not available to install from CRAN nor is it attached as base package.

Does anybody know whether this package will be available for R soon?

Maybe it's for interest, but when I run `sessionInfo()` I get

```
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] de_AT.UTF-8/de_AT.UTF-8/de_AT.UTF-8/C/de_AT.UTF-8/de_AT.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.5
```

Comment: It's still part of the core R distribution. It hasn't been dropped. If `library(parallel)` doesn't do it for you, then there's something wrong with your R installation.

Comment: I've reinstalled R and now ```library(parallel)``` is working. Anyway, thanks!